# Access data from specific cell in sparse Excel file with Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I've got an Excel file that doesn't have data in all rows, and I may or may not know which rows contain data. Say that I want to access the data from a specific cell (in this case C9), but not all rows leading up to 9 include data.

The code below would work if all rows leading up to 9 had data, but when they do not, some are not included in the DF and therefore we cannot simply access the data on index 8, 2.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel(file_path)
        cell_c9_value = df.iloc[8, 2]
        print(cell_c9_value)
```

Comment: Can you show how look like your spreadsheet and/or make a meaningful example + the expected output ?

Comment: Do you need to use pandas to read the data into df. What if you use openpyxl to read the cell or the sheet? I can provide an answer for openpyxl if it helps.

Comment: @Timeless https://imgur.com/AXU0qVa

Comment: @FuatUlugay was wondering if there was a way of doing it with Pandas, but tried using openpyxl and it works like a charm!

Comment: @LegendWK great to hear that. I provided a code that is working for my sheet example and getting C9 value. I wonder if it also helps?

Answer (score 0):

data frame after reading excel
[image: data frame after reading excel]

Excel sheet
[image: Excel sheet]

Code:

```
import pandas as pd

file_path = 'Book1.xlsx'
# Read the Excel file and skip empty rows
df = pd.read_excel(file_path, skiprows=lambda x: x > 8 )

# Access the data from cell C9
cell_c9_value = df.iloc[7, 2]
print(cell_c9_value)
```

Output:

```
6.0
```

I hope this helps.

I have created my own excel file as a sample. You can still modify the excel and values to meet your requirements.

Comment: This only works if you know ahead of time how many rows there is information in, right? What if there sometimes is data in b2 and sometimes there isn't?

Comment: here provided that the first row is column names you can read any range that you define and refer to any cell. I wonder if you are trying to find until which last column and row there is data and read that range?

Comment: For example in the code you can change lambda x: x > 50 it will not put more rows to data frame after last row with data. Assume that the last row number with data is 10. you will see 10 rows in your DF.

Comment: one more thing: x is just for limiting the rows. It will also work without it. I think your main issue was that the first row is column name and for C9 you should refer [7, 2] instead of [8, 2]. Please see the dataframe and excel screenshots.